# Issue about customizing Editor Map extent

Tags: extents, geonetwork

We're working with GeoNetwork 3.12.9 and we're trying to set, within Editor Map Configuration of the Administrator User Interface, a map other than the default one (osm). Once saved the custom configuration, the map is shown when editing a record, but with incorrect extent (full extent). It seems that GeoNetwork doesn't read the configured extent (the bounding box values are compliant with the system reference of editor's Geographic bounding box).
Does it exist another way to configure this option or is this a known issue?
Thanks[image]

[image]